# Python - 3D plotting of 2 functions

Tags: python, arrays, 3d

iam not really good at python and I need your help.
First I am going to show you what I already did and how it works, then iam going to ask my question.

The following code is working and iam trying to explain what iam doing:

```
import numpy as np                  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint          
from scipy import integrate 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.ticker import LinearLocator, FormatStrFormatter
#======================================================
def eq(par,initial_cond,start_t,end_t,incr):
     # time-grid-----------------------------------
     t  = np.linspace(start_t, end_t,incr)      
     # differential-eq-system----------------------
     def funct(y,t):                    
        A=y[0]                      
        k_1A=par
        # the model equations   
        dgl_A = -k_1A * A 
        dgl_B = k_1A * A 
        return [dgl_A, dgl_B]       
     #integrate------------------------------------
     ds = integrate.odeint(funct,initial_cond,t)                
     return (ds[:,0],ds[:,1],t) 

#=======================================================

# rates 
k_1A = 50   
rates=(k_1A)        
# initial conditions at t=0
A0 = 0.034                  
B0 = 0.074              
y0 = [A0, B0]       # initial condition vector

F7,F1,T=eq(rates,y0,0,1.,100)
#saving F1 into F20
F20=F1

 ############################################################################
def gaussian(Y, mu, sig,N0):
    return N0*np.exp(-np.power(Y - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))

n=100
laser1 = np.arange(n)                      #array for frequency
laser3=np.arange(n,dtype=np.float)         #array for gaussian



for i in laser1:
     k_1A = 50*gaussian(i,50,10,1)     
     rates=(k_1A)       
     F7,F1,T=eq(rates,y0,0,1.,100)                  
     laser3[i]=F1[1]  


############ plotting #############################
f = plt.figure()
plt.plot(laser1,laser3,'-r', linewidth=2.0)
f = plt.figure()
plt.plot(T,F20)
plt.show()
```

I have 2 DGL's (reaction A ->B, with rate k_1A), and iam solving them in the first part. Later I can plot the F20=F1 (this is the number in state B) vs. time T. In the for-loop, iam calculating a new rate k_1A (depending on a gaussian) and consequently new numbers in B, i.e. F1, and saving them at a certain time into laser3 (laser3[i]=F1[1.]). Then i plot laser3 vs laser 1 and get a Gaussian.

Now, what do i need?
I want to plot this into a 3D graph, so that on x axis is the time, on y axis the frequency(laser1) and on z axis the number of B (F20/F1).
I did this for an analytically case, as shown in the following figure:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGhCi.png)

So i want on one axis the gaussian vs frequency and on the other number of B (F20=F1) vs time. I hope you guys understood what i meant and what iam trying to do. I hope you can help me.
Thanks a lot.